# Remove First occurance of an element from list python

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
List_main = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']

List_sub = ['c','f','d']
```

I now joined these lists into:

```
 list_joined = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','c','f','d']
```

I want to remove the first occurrences of elements in List_sub from the joined list  'list_joined'.

Final output i am looking for is to obtain a list which has the `List_sub` elements appended at the end.:

```
['a','b','e','g','h','c','f','d']
```

I tried an approach where i found out the index of sub_list elements from the `List_main`.

```
[i for i,x in enumerate(path_stores_new) if x == value ]
```

and then use

```
del list_joined[index]
```

But i think there may be a better way of doing this.
Any leads?

Note: `List_main` has unique values

Comment: how would `list_joined` look if `List_main` was `['a','b','c', 'c']`?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis List Main has unique values

Comment: i would suggest the remove method from the list itself `list_joined.remove(list_joined2[0])` after the list_joined is made

Comment: How about `list_joined = [x for x in List_main if x not in List_sub] + List_sub`

Comment: @RodolfoDonãHosp I'm looking for is to obtain a list which has the `List_sub` elements appended at the end of the `List_main`

Comment: Oh, sorry, thought you just wanted to remove the first occurence, didn't notice it is specific to this input

Comment: @Ev.Kounis The answer Works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you can also use the built-in `filter` function like this:

```
List_main = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
List_sub = ['c','f','d']

sub_filter = lambda x: x not in List_sub
list_joined = list(filter(sub_filter, List_main)) + List_sub
```

This will output `['a', 'b', 'e', 'g', 'h', 'c', 'f', 'd']`.

Answer (score 1):

Can be done easily using a list comprehension

a one liner for this is as in the code below:

```
List_main = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
List_sub = ['c','f','d']

list_joined = [i for i in List_main if i not in List_sub] + List_sub
```

**EDIT:**

The above code ignored all the occurrences if only the first occurrence is to be ignored the code below should do the job.

```
List_main = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
List_sub = ['c','f','d']

list_joined = [value for ind, value in enumerate(List_main) if value not in List_sub or ind > List_main.index(value)] + List_sub
```

Comment: This solution **does not** ignore the first occurrence. Instead, it ignores all occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `List_main` to a dict first, delete the keys based on `List_sub`, and then join the remaining keys with `List_sub`, so that the removal of each element in `List_sub` can be done in an average time complexity of O(1) (otherwise element lookup and removal in list and would cost an average of O(n) per element):

```
dict_main = dict.fromkeys(List_main)
for k in List_sub:
    del dict_main[k]
print(list(dict_main) + List_sub)
```

This outputs:

```
['a', 'b', 'e', 'g', 'h', 'c', 'f', 'd']
```

If you aren't using Python 3.7 you can use `collections.OrderedDict` instead of `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do exactly the same as @Rakesh, I'm just sending what I would have done even though our answers are very very similar. :)

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr_2 = [2, 3]
for elem in arr_2:
    if elem in arr:
        arr.remove(elem)

arr += arr_2
print(arr)
# [1, 4, 5, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter elements of first list witch not in the second, and then extend the result with the second list  :

```
List_main = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
List_sub = ['c','f','d']
list(filter(lambda x : x not in List_sub, List_main)) + List_sub
```

Output :

```
['a', 'b', 'e', 'g', 'h', 'c', 'f', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from itertools import filterfalse

def f(x):
     if x in List_sub:
         List_sub.remove(x)
         return True
     return False

list(filterfalse(f, list_joined))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this, if you want to ignore the first occurrence:

```
List_main = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
List_sub = ['c','f','d']
dict_main = dict.fromkeys(List_sub)
list_joined = []

for x in List_main:
if x in dict_main.keys():
    if dict_main[x] is None:
        dict_main[x] = 1
    else:
        list_joined += x
else:
    list_joined += x
list_joined += List_sub

print(list_joined)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can remove it using this code:

```
list_main = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']

list_sub = ['c','f','d']
for sub_item in list_sub:
    if sub_item in list_main:
        list_main.remove(sub_item)
list_main += sub_item
```

Or just not add a duplicated items:

```
list_main = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']

list_sub = ['c','f','d']
for sub_item in list_sub:
    if sub_item not in list_main:
        list_main.append(sub_item)
```

Also if you don't want to have duplicated items you can use `set`. But be careful, `set` doesn't keep your initial order of elements.

```
list_main = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
list_sub = ['c','f','d']
result_list = list(set(list_main + list_sub))
```

Comment: Note: sets don't preserve the order! Which means in this case it might not be a viable solution, as you cannot guarantee to get the desired output as specified in the question.

Comment: @MikeScotty, of course, the last example doesn't work if an order is important. I should specify it. But I've written that this is a solution to remove all the duplicates.